# How does higher carbonyl compounds disolve in water?

Tags: carbonyl-compounds

We know that higher the carbon, the more is hydrophobic the compound nature is, Still when we take a compound like sugar , a hand of sugar, it readily dissolves in water? can someone explain me reg this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugar contains a lot of hydroxyl groups. So due to hydrogen bonds, sugar can readily dissolves in water.